# Get multiple elements from node request and then choose one

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

My request gets multiple a tags from a page, and do some string manipulation on them. My problem is choosing just one string. My output is

```
string 1
string 2
string 3
etc...
```

I just want for instance

```
string 2
```

And when I do something like `console.log(a[2])` , I'll get the second `'t' in 'http'`

How can I do this with the following code on my request

```
request(url, function (error, response, html) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    var $ = cheerio.load(html);
    //parse to find cards
    $('div.card').each(function(i, element){
      //find all links
      a = ($(this).find('a').attr('href'));
      a = a.split('/')[3];
      //construct new string
      visiting = "http://api.website.com/stuff/"+a
      console.log(a);
      });
    };
  });
```

Comment: Try `$('div.card a:contains("string 2")')`.

Comment: are your sure the t is from `http` not `string`

Comment: Every time your desired output will be depending on what? For this instance you want string 2, every time how will you differentiate the choosing one string out of all.

Comment: @Tushar solution works if data is known, but in this instance, it is not

Comment: @KunalKhatri the string to be chosen would be based on a random number. So if a[position] was correct syntax, then a[ran_num] = string 5. Does this make sense?

Comment: You can use nth-child(ran_num) instead of making an each loop, just use like below,
a = ($('div.card:nth-child("+ran_num+")').find('a').attr('href'));

Answer (score 0):

try this,
as i understand you need to add all tags in an array and then you can get elements by index

```
    request(url, function (error, response, html) {
      if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            var $ = cheerio.load(html);
            //parse to find cards
            var a=[];
            $('div.card').each(function(i, element){
                  tag = $(this).find('a').attr('href').split('/')[3]
                  //construct new string
                  visiting = "http://api.website.com/stuff/"+tag
                  a.push(tag);
              });
            console.log(a[2]);
        };
      });
```

//edit 1

you can use this function

```
    function getRandomInt(max) {
      return Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(max));
    }
```

in you code as follows:

```
    request(url, function (error, response, html) {
      if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            var $ = cheerio.load(html);
            //parse to find cards
            var a=[];
            $('div.card').each(function(i, element){
                  tag = $(this).find('a').attr('href').split('/')[3]
                  //construct new string
                  visiting = "http://api.website.com/stuff/"+tag
                  a.push(tag);
              });
            //get random tag
            console.log(a[getRandomInt(a.length)]);
        };
      });
```